# how to join two table in symfony2 DQL query

Tags: symfony

```
$var=$em->createQuery('SELECT a, p FROM AdminBundle:Appraisal a
       LEFT JOIN AdminBundle:AppResult p ON a.id=p.Appraisalid');
```

I want to query between two table but this is not working

Comment: D2 uses meta data to simplify the join syntax. http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins

Answer (score 1):

you must use mapping associations between objects.
one to many 
OR 
one to one
OR
many to many?
if AdminBundle:Appraisal has many AdminBundle:AppResult (ONE TO MANY), you must mapp this two entity like this:
in Appraisal.php make this changes:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppResult", mappedBy="raisal")
 **/
private $results;
// ...

public function __construct() {
    $this->results = new Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

and in AppResult.php make this changes:

```
 /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Appraisal", inversedBy="results")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="result_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $raisal;
```

now update your entities :

`php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AdminBundle:Appraisal`

`php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AdminBundle:AppResult`

update your schema:
`php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

now you can make query like this:

```
$var=$em->createQuery('SELECT a, p FROM AdminBundle:Appraisal a
       LEFT JOIN a.results p');
```

hope its help U.
full help can be found [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html)